# Difference between DNS Reslover and Recursor?

Tags: domain-name-system

What is the difference between DNS resolver and DNS recursor?

What are their core responsibilities?

Why "A DNS recursor is a resolver but a DNS reslover is not a DNS recursor?

Comment: This may help you understand about DNS:  https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-server-types/

Comment: Also relevant: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7719

Answer (score 3):

*Resolver* is a broader term; there are multiple forms of resolvers, one of which is the *recursive mode resolver* (aka *recursor*).

Another very common form of resolver is the *stub resolver*, essentially the regular name resolution library/service included with operating systems, which only sends queries (having `RD` set) to one or more configured *recursive mode resolvers* (or *forwarders*).

RFC7719 is an informational document covering DNS terminology, you may want to consult [section 5, DNS Servers and Clients](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7719#section-5).